# Duplicated data on sql request

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I'm having some issues with my sql request. They all work 1 by 1, but when i join them to make a global request it duplicate all my joined data.
Here is my actual global request, it work but not the way i would like. 
I have already tried things but can't find the answer to my problem.
Thanks for your help.

```
SELECT films.titre,films.annee,films.description,films.image_film, 
GROUP_CONCAT(genre.type SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre,
GROUP_CONCAT(realisateur.realisateur SEPARATOR ', ') AS realisateur,
GROUP_CONCAT(acteur.acteur SEPARATOR ', ') AS acteur
FROM film_genre 
INNER JOIN films ON film_genre.film = films.id
INNER JOIN film_realisateur ON film_realisateur.film = films.id
INNER JOIN realisateur ON realisateur.id = film_realisateur.realisateur
INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = film_genre.genre
INNER JOIN film_acteur ON film_acteur.film = films.id
INNER JOIN acteur ON acteur.id = film_acteur.acteur
GROUP BY films.titre
```

Comment: Can you share what data you are getting and what do you expect?

Comment: Here is a print of the result of this request : 

https://imgur.com/bX4jxio

As you can see in the columns "genre, realisateur and acteur" the datas are duplicated, i would like to show it only one time

Comment: Can you use `distinct`? e.g. `GROUP_CONCAT( distinct genre.type SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre`

Comment: Thanks you for your help, i did the DISTINCT thing but after the SELECT... It work now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct request, thank to Aman B :)

```
SELECT films.titre,films.annee,films.description,films.image_film, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genre.type SEPARATOR ', ') AS genre,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT realisateur.realisateur SEPARATOR ', ') AS realisateur,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT acteur.acteur SEPARATOR ', ') AS acteur
FROM film_genre 
INNER JOIN films ON film_genre.film = films.id
INNER JOIN film_realisateur ON film_realisateur.film = films.id
INNER JOIN realisateur ON realisateur.id = film_realisateur.realisateur
INNER JOIN genre ON genre.id = film_genre.genre
INNER JOIN film_acteur ON film_acteur.film = films.id
INNER JOIN acteur ON acteur.id = film_acteur.acteur
GROUP BY films.titre
```